# How to empty a very large mysql table?

Tags: mysql, command-line

Whenever I try to empty a large table so using

```
truncate table the_huge_table;
```

and wait for several minutes, I see nothing take place. 
On the other hand I do not want to remove the entire table because not sure how to regenerate it so wondering what is the best way to easily empty this monster?

Comment: Not off-topic, it's very easily expressed in code and it relates to programming.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`SHOW CREATE TABLE the_huge_table` will show you how to recreate the table if you drop it.

Another option is to clone the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE cloned LIKE the_huge_table;
RENAME TABLE the_huge_table TO drop_me, cloned TO the_huge_table;
DROP TABLE drop_me;
```

Comment: +1 Didn't know about the `cloned` keyword. That will be really useful for me in the future.

Comment: @Michael, `cloned` **IS NOT A KEYWORD** Please don't be confused. All the keywords in jeffs answer are in CAPITALS

Comment: @Johan Yes I figured that out when I started looking for documentation. Anyway, I didn't know about `CREATE TABLE LIKE`

Answer (score 4):

```
mysqldump --no-data dbname tablename > /tmp/backup.sql
mysql -e 'drop table tablename' dbname
mysql dbname < /tmp/backup.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy the structure to a new, empty table.
Drop the old table.
Rename the empty copy.

```
CREATE TABLE copy_huge_table LIKE the_huge_table;
DROP TABLE the_huge_table;
RENAME TABLE copy_huge_table TO the_huge_table;
```

Comment: Johan, you need to add TABLE in the second and third lines.